# WKInterfaceButton event handling in WKInterfaceTable

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, watchkit

I have a `WKInterfaceTable` table view with a `WKInterfaceButton`.

How can I add a target action to the button from the table view. As there is no tag property I am not able to handle it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `WKInterfaceButton` is contained within a row controller, here is one method to determine which row's button was tapped:

- Add your `WKInterfaceButton` to the row controller and use interface builder to connect the button's action to your row controller class
- Add a property to your row controller that allows you to reference your data (for example, a weak reference to your data or a tag)
- Add a property to your row controller that allows you to set your interface controller as a delegate
- Create a protocol for the delegate that allows you to pass the data reference
- When initializing each row controller, be sure to set the data and delegate properties
- When the button action is handled in the row controller, call the delegate method that you defined in your protocol. Something like:

  `- (void)rowController:(MyRowControllerClass *)rowController didSelectRowWithTag:(NSInteger)tag`
- Handle this delegate method in your interface controller to do whatever work is necessary.

I use this technique in my own Watch app, and it works very well.

Comment: +1 for the detailed answer. There are properties like setAccessibilityHint which is similar to tag but won't be useful because no getters so I think this is the only way to achieve this.

Comment: @Mike Swason I did not understand complete explanation..can u provide some sample code for it?