# WKInterfaceGroup in table highlights contained button on touch down

Tags: watchos, wkinterfacetable, wkinterfacegroup, wkinterfacebutton

I have found if you implement a `WKInterfaceTable`, the row controller contains a `WKInterfaceGroup`, and if you add two `WKInterfaceButton`s to the group, one of which is disabled (or hidden), and you tap down on this button, it will highlight the entire row as if you were touching down on both buttons. This does not occur with a regular `WKInterfaceGroup` outside of a table. How can one disable this highlight behavior for the entire group in the table row?

Here is an [example project](https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/0c0Z2O0X3b3u3s3W2C37/Test.zip?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJEFUZRCWSLB2QA5Q&Expires=1473115921&Signature=4RA37UQFEW6Tuhv1FjIXe8WuvbI%3D&response-content-disposition=attachment) that demonstrates the undesired behavior. B2 is disabled, yet touching down on it highlights the entire group. Note that the project should be opened with Xcode 8, as it's a watchOS 3 app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select tableCell in storyboard

[image]

remove checkmark from Selectable item

[image]

Now you are able to single-tap on button in a row. 
If you need to get index of tapped button, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391698/wkinterfacebutton-event-handling-in-wkinterfacetable).